# Speed up keyboard macro execution in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Intellij keyboard macros are nice, but also are terribly slow and I wonder if anything can be done to improve it. I have a keyboard macro defined to format the current block of code:

```xml
   <macro name="reformat block macro">
      <action id="ToggleBookmark9" />
      <action id="EditorCodeBlockEnd" />
      <action id="EditorToggleStickySelection" />
      <action id="EditorCodeBlockStart" />
      <action id="EditorLineStart" />
      <action id="EditorLineStart" />
      <action id="ReformatCode" />
      <action id="GotoBookmark9" />
      <action id="ToggleBookmark9" />
    </macro>
```

When running this, it is like watching a slow typing person perform the steps, since each action is rendered. Is there a way to speed this up, some hidden switch to avoids the live rendering of intermediate steps?

Comment: Does [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-316721/Macro-Speed-is-Slow#focus=Comments-27-7064773.0-0) help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the macro command execution delay in the registry. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> and type "Registry" or press <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, find the `actionSystem.playback.typecommand.delay` key, and change the value from the default 200ms to a smaller value.

Also, a word of warning: I've experienced non-deterministic macro playback behavior when setting the delay too low.